# Using _crtBreakAlloc to find memory leaks - identifier "_crtBreakAlloc" is unidentified

Tags: c, memory-leaks, crt

I am trying to use `_crtBreakAlloc` in the Watch window as suggested in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx) link, but the value line says that 'identifier "_crtBreakAlloc" is unidentified' and it simply does not work.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Visual Studio by the way.

An example of code:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <malloc.h>


int main()
{
    int *arr = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); //breakpoint here
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

I then write _crtBreakAlloc into the Name field of the Watch window and hit enter when encountering the breakpoint.

Comment: Make sure you're using the debug version (`/MTd` or `/MDd`).

Comment: Where do I put those flags?

Comment: Sounds like a coding problem.  Please post the code.  Otherwise we can only make WAGs.

Comment: @Sunspawn: Unless you've changed the project properties (C/C++ -> Code Generation), just use the `Debug ` and not `Release` configuration. Also make sure to do this: `If you are using the multithreaded DLL version of the CRT library (the /MD option), include the context operator: {,,msvcr100d.dll}_crtBreakAlloc` (for VS2013 it's `msvcr120d`).

Comment: I am using the default F5 debug mode. Is that something different?

Comment: Okay, apparently I WAS using the /MD one - only now it tells me that "module msvcr100d.dll is not found" - despite it being right there in the System32 folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_crtBreakAlloc` is a macro under VS2015 that is replaced by a call to a function returning a pointer to an int. Tracking a variable in the watch window doesn't seem an option.
Better insert in your (debug) code something like this:

```
_crtBreakAlloc = 18;
```

Answer (score 9):

_crtBreakAlloc will be reported as unidentified if the ucrtbased.dll symbols are not loaded. I had this problem because I do not automatically load my symbols. You can go in your module list and manually Load symbols for ucrtbased.dll and then _crtBreakAlloc should show up and work.

Comment: Had same issue! Note, this applies to e.g. VS 2019 where you use `{,,ucrtbased.dll}_crtBreakAlloc` as other answer suggests. Likely this page could be used to guess whatever symbol name should be used in future versions - [Visual Studio documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 4):

few options:

- add **{,,ucrtbased.dll }_crtBreakAlloc** as variable to Watch

this requires symbols loaded in order watch window to display variable type correctly

find out which CRT version **crt*.dll** you compile against. (new ucrtbase**d**.dll, older msvcrt**d***.dll, etc) 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019

load all modules, or add manually into \tools\options\debug\symbols\load only spec modules

note: your Debug config compile with /MD**d** (it will have _DEBUG defined)

Release config compile with /MD  (most of debug macros just zero;)

- use **memchk_break** macro as bellow, it will show alloc block in locals automatically

(since it resolves through compilation)

- let it run, pass on first break, let it print mem leaks if any

- on second round, type in the alloc block into variable, run and catch

---

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
   #define memchk_break() { auto& _ab = _crtBreakAlloc; __debugbreak(); }
#else
   #define memchk_break() 0;
#endif
void main(){
   memchk_break();
   // your code
   _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{,,ucrtbased.dll}*__p__crtBreakAlloc()
```

works for Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the multithread version of the CRT, enter the following in the
watch window (in column name) :

```
(int*){,,ucrtbased.dll}_crtBreakAlloc
```

then press enter and change the value -1 to the new allocation number that causes a user-defined breakpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for Visual Studio 2015 it is necessary to use two underscores:

```
(int*){,,ucrtbased.dll}__crtBreakAlloc
```