# _crtBreakAlloc in VS2017

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2017, crt

I try to find out memory leaks using CRT. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community.
I followed the [official help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/151585/how-to-use-crtbreakalloc-to-debug-a-memory-allocation),
but its not working.

I tried different inputs in Watch window. That's what I get:

> _crtBreakAlloc    identifier "_crtBreakAlloc" is undefined

I tried suggestions I've found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357986/using-crtbreakalloc-to-find-memory-leaks-identifier-crtbreakalloc-is-unide) and got the same results:

> (int*){,,ucrtbased.dll}_crtBreakAlloc identifier "_crtBreakAlloc" is undefined
>
> (int*){,,ucrtbased.dll}__crtBreakAlloc    identifier "__crtBreakAlloc" is undefined

Debug build, runtime library Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd).

I tried calling function `_CrtSetBreakAlloc` and it works.

So is re-compiling and calling this function the only option?
Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
{,,ucrtbased.dll}_crtBreakAlloc
```

Make sure symbols are loaded (Tools / Options / Debugging / Symbols).